# How to get .NET StandardOutput and StandardError out of PowerShell Function

Tags: .net, powershell, error-handling, output

I am trying to create a wrapper function for PowerShell cmdlets that do not accept the -credential parameter, using https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-command-as-a-different-user-in-powershell/ as a guide. The problem is that I am not able to get meaningful output about the success or failure of those cmdlets.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm launching powershell.exe as the user whose credentials are stored in $PSCreds, and I'm feeding the new powershell process the cmdlet to be run under that user's context, and expecting to get the results from that cmdlet in the parent script. So, Script1 executes under UserA's permissions/context, but needs to run  as UserB; however,  doesn't accept the -Credential flag, so I need to call this function. I need the output of  as UserB from this function in Script1 to make decisions about what happens next in Script1.

I've read a lot of things about redirecting output, but I don't understand it. I've tried moving the .waitforexit() to after the .readtoend(). I've tried doing `return $getprocessresult`. I've tried doing another variable to assign the standarderror and an `if ($errortext) {return $errortext}` and stuff like that, but no success.

This is a stripped-down version of my function, doesn't show everything, but shows (what I think are) the relevant sections.

```
Function start-PSCMDAsUser {
Param (
        [String[]]$PSCMDArgs,
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]$PSCreds
        ) #Close Param declaration
    $ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
    $ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
    $ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $ProcessInfo.Arguments = $PSCMDArgs
    $ProcessInfo.Username = $PSCreds.GetNetworkCredential().username
    $ProcessInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
    $Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
    $Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 
    $Process.Start() | Out-Null 
    $Process.WaitForExit() 
    $GetProcessResult = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $GetProcessResult
    } #close function start-pscmdasuser
```

I'm using `$PSCMDArgs = 'New-Item -Path ' + $testfile + ' -ItemType "file" -Value ' + "Tested_Share_$datetime"` as input for 
`start-PSCMDAsUser -PSCreds $pscreds -PSCMDArgs $PSCMDArgs`

I have another function (test-myshares) that calls this function in a `foreach ($share in $shares)` loop. I would expect to see the output of this function interspersed within the parent function, and in fact, I'd like the `test-myshares` function to be able to use output from this function to intelligently generate output. But I can't get the `start-pscmdasuser` function to output the way you'd expect. In fact, what I get is all the verbose output from `test-myshares` *and then* the last bit of the last variable in the `start-pscmdasuser` function

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to `try {start-PSCMDAsUser -PSCreds $pscreds -PSCMDArgs $PSCMDArgs } catch {do-something}` but I'm not sure how to get the .NET output to work. I appreciate any help!

**Edit:** Let's say I'm using a script to set FSRM File Screens (this is just an example, and not actually something I'm doing; this is just to illustrate the intent). I'll run the FSRM cmdlets in a script to configure them all, and then I want the script to test the File Screens by using the target user's credentials to write a new file of the screened type using new-item. Well, the new-item cmdlet doesn't accept -Credential when you use "-itemtype file", so I need to run the New-Item under the target user's context to avoid passing -credential. I'd like to use this function. And the parent script needs to know if the New-Item succeeded or failed (and WHY) to validate the new File Screens. But how do I pass that output back into the Script? That's my problem, and I'm hoping you can help! Thank you again!!

Comment: It does not appear you are ever passing an executable to start, is that elsewhere in the script?

Comment: Yep! Got carried away in my efforts at stripping down, I've edited to re-add both the process and one of the three lines where I use $PSCreds. Thanks for calling that out!